# XSLT correct syntaksis for dynamic calling of elemnts by variable value

Tags: xml, xslt

Please help me how to output text of element with dynamic calling

source XML

```
<GTD>
  <LINE>
    <G44>
      <G441>
        02015
      </G441>
      <G442>
        12345
      </G442>
    </G44>
  </LINE>
</GTD>
```

My xsl transformation

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<GTD>
  <LINE>
    <VAR_1_1>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../G44[G441 = '02015' or G441 = '02016' or G441 = '02017']">
        <xsl:with-param name="field" select="G441" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </VAR_1_1>
    <VAR_1_2>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../G44[G441 = '02015' or G441 = '02016' or G441 = '02017']">
        <xsl:with-param name="field" select="G442" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </VAR_1_2>
  </LINE>
</GTD>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="G44[G441 = '02015' or G441 = '02016' or G441 = '02017']">
  <xsl:param name="field"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$field" />
</xsl:template>
```

And i realy know that `<xsl:value-of select="$field" />` will give me value of variable but not value of the element with name equal variable value.

So, in fact I only need correct syntaksis for dynamic calling of elemnts by variable value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your parameter will always be empty, because you are in the context of the `/` root element and you are selecting a node. There is no `G441` element that is a child of the `/`root node, so you are selecting nothing.

The way you are going at it, you need to send a **string** as the parameter, e.g.

```
<xsl:with-param name="field" select="'G441'" />
```

then extract the value as:

```
<xsl:value-of select="*[name()=$field]" />
```

---

Note also that:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="../G44[G441 = '02015' or G441 = '02016' or G441 = '02017']">
```

also doesn't do anything. I think you meant this to be:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select=".//G44[G441 = '02015' or G441 = '02016' or G441 = '02017']">
```

or (preferably):

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="GTD/LINE/G44[G441 = '02015' or G441 = '02016' or G441 = '02017']">
```

---

IMHO, you could simplify the whole thing to:

```
<xsl:template match="/GTD">
    <GTD>
      <LINE>
        <xsl:variable name="g44" select="LINE/G44[G441='02015' or G441='02016' or G441='02017']" />
        <VAR_1_1>
            <xsl:value-of select="$g44/G441" />
        </VAR_1_1>
        <VAR_1_2>
            <xsl:value-of select="$g44/G442" />
        </VAR_1_2>
      </LINE>
    </GTD>
</xsl:template>
```